# MariaDB - sql query performance or optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, mariadb

I have a stored procedure. A little problematic in terms of performance. I want to improve the performance of the stored procedure, but I could not figure out what to do. There are approximately 3 million records in my database. When I run this query one by one, it's good in performance. But when 150 people run this stored procedure at the same time, there are spikes in the CPU.

As an example, I created my procedure and table structures.

My Stored Procedure:

```
BEGIN
SELECT ss.car_route from person o
inner join car_time ss on ss.inst_id =o.inst_id  
and ss.start_time<=DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')  AND  ss.finish_time>= date_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i') AND ss.car_id=carid
and ss.days like concat('%',(select WEEKDAY(now())+1),'%') 
where (o.car_id=carid or o.back_car_id=carid ) LIMIT 1 into @route_;
select sf.stop_service from car_comp sf 
inner join cars s on s.inst_id = sf.id and s.id=carid and s.active=1 limit 1
into @stop_ser;



if @route_ = 1 and @stop_ser=0 THEN

select DISTINCT ss.start_time,ss.finish_time ,o.id,o.name,r.photo, oh.state ,oh.datee,ss.car_route,
ifnull(bh.id,0) AS called,
ifnull(mh.excuse_id,0) AS excuse_id,
ifnull(o.latitude_1,0) AS latitude_1,
ifnull(o.longitude_1,0) AS longitude_1,
ifnull(o.latitude_2,0) AS latitude_2,
ifnull(o.longitude_2,0) AS longitude_2,
case when (ifnull(o.call_notify,0)=1 or ifnull(o.mes_notify,0)=1) then 1 else 0 end AS call_notify ,
ifnull(o.rownumber,0) AS rownumber,
ifnull(o.number_1,0) AS number_1,
ifnull(o.number_2,0) AS number_2,
ifnull(o.brownumber,0) AS brownumber,
ifnull(ROUND(o.notify_meter_1/2),0) AS notify_meter_1,
ifnull(ROUND(o.notify_meter_2/2),0) AS notify_meter_2
from person o
inner join car_time ss on ss.inst_id =o.inst_id and o.car_id=ss.car_id
and ss.start_time<=DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')  AND  ss.finish_time>= date_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
and ss.days like concat('%',(select WEEKDAY(now())+1),'%')

LEFT JOIN notify_records bh ON bh.table_id=o.id AND bh.car_route=@route_
and bh.table_name='person' AND bh.notify=4 AND bh.car_id=o.car_id and bh.date_ >= CURDATE() and bh.date_ < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY 

left join  person_records oh   on  oh.person_id=o.id
and oh.car_id=o.car_id
and date_format(oh.datee,'%H:%i') >=ss.start_time
and date_format(oh.datee,'%H:%i') <=ss.finish_time
AND oh.car_route= @route_
and
oh.id in(select max(id) from person_records
where date_time >= CURDATE() and date_time < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and car_id = carid and car_id = carid
GROUP by person_id
)
left join inst ok on o.inst_id = ok.id and o.car_id=carid
left join excuse_records mh on mh.person_id=o.id and mh.date_time >= CURDATE() and mh.date_time < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and (mh.car_route=ss.car_route)
left join photo_ r on r.table_id = o.id and r.table_name = 'person'
where
(ss.car_route=o.cars_route_ or o.cars_route_=3) and

o.car_id = carid and o.active=1
AND o.work_time=ss.work_time;


elseif @route_ = 2 and @stop_ser=0 then

select DISTINCT ss.start_time,ss.finish_time ,o.id,o.name,r.photo, oh.state ,oh.datee,ss.car_route,
ifnull(bh.id,0) AS called,
ifnull(mh.excuse_id,0) AS excuse_id,
ifnull(o.latitude_1,0) AS latitude_1,
ifnull(o.longitude_1,0) AS longitude_1,
ifnull(o.latitude_2,0) AS latitude_2,
ifnull(o.longitude_2,0) AS longitude_2,
case when (ifnull(o.call_notify,0)=1 or ifnull(o.mes_notify,0)=1) then 1 else 0 end AS call_notify ,
ifnull(o.rownumber,0) AS rownumber,
ifnull(o.number_1,0) AS number_1,
ifnull(o.number_2,0) AS number_2,
ifnull(o.brownumber,0) AS brownumber,
ifnull(ROUND(o.notify_meter_1/2),0) AS notify_meter_1,
ifnull(ROUND(o.notify_meter_2/2),0) AS notify_meter_2
from person o
inner join car_time ss on ss.inst_id =o.inst_id and o.back_car_id=ss.car_id
and ss.start_time<=DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')  AND  ss.finish_time>= date_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
and ss.days like concat('%',(select WEEKDAY(now())+1),'%')
LEFT JOIN notify_records bh ON bh.table_id=o.id AND bh.car_route=@route_
and bh.table_name='person' AND bh.notify=4 AND bh.car_id=o.back_car_id and bh.date_ >= CURDATE() and bh.date_ < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY  
left join  person_records oh   on  oh.person_id=o.id
and oh.car_id=o.back_car_id and oh.car_route=2
and date_format(oh.datee,'%H:%i') >=ss.start_time
and date_format(oh.datee,'%H:%i') <=ss.finish_time
AND oh.car_route= @route_
and
oh.id in (select max(id) from person_records
where date_time >= CURDATE() and date_time < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and car_id = carid
GROUP by person_id
)
left join inst ok on o.inst_id = ok.id and o.car_id=carid
left join excuse_records mh on mh.person_id=o.id and mh.date_time >= CURDATE() and mh.date_time < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY and (mh.car_route=ss.car_route)
left join photo_ r on r.table_id = o.id and r.table_name = 'person'
where
(ss.car_route=o.cars_route_ or o.cars_route_=3) and

o.back_car_id = carid and o.active=1
AND o.work_time=ss.work_time;


END IF;


end
```

[I have a database example here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=49ca194c3899e8a0d5e0710ea5dc9800)

I made my.cnf improvement but still have difficulties with performance. What is wrong with this query? What can I change?

Thank you from now.

Edit:

Server version: 10.1.41-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

I have indexes. I forgot to add indexes while creating test data.

Comment: I am no MySQL guy, so I am not the one to help here. What I do notice is that your pick of @route_  and @stop_ser seem quite arbitrary. Of all routes matching the day and time span you simply pick one with no further rule applied. Then you pick one active stop_route, again not applying any rule which to pick. You are joining, where I'd rather expect an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause. You make a time a string rather than working with times. You store several week days in a string rather than have a separate table.

Comment: Then, your main queries start with `SELECT DISTINCT`. This is very, very often a sign for a badly written query. Why must you remove duplicates? Hopefully, your database is normalized, so there are no duplicates in that. Probably it's you yourself, blindly joining tables and thus creating a too large intermediate result that you must then condense again. Ask yourself why you are getting duplicates and avoid creating them in the first place. Then remove `distinct` and your queries should run much better.

Comment: in your fiddle examle the re are no indexes,. there should be all columns that are in an ON or WHERE clause in a cobined INDEX.

Comment: Maybe it's again `IN` or `EXISTS` instead of a join that can help with these main queries. I don't know, because I haven't looked at your queries more closely. And, yes, nbk is right mentioning that you'll want appropriate indexes.

Comment: Hello there. First of all, thank you for your answer. There are 2 directions during the day. For example, between 7 and 9 o'clock before noon route_ = 1 in the afternoon between 15 and 17 o'clock route_ = 2. And this only applies to 1 car. And I use the variable stop_ser to stop the service of some companies. @ThorstenKettner

Comment: My database is normalized. There is an index for on and where statements. But I forgot to add them when creating the Test data. @nbk

Comment: @storedprocedure then add them please.

Answer (score 0):

What the heck is this?

```
ss.days like concat('%',(select WEEKDAY(now())+1),'%')
```

It can at least be sped up by changing to

```
ss.days like concat('%',WEEKDAY(now()),'%')
```

And, won't that lead to checking against 2, 21, 20, 12, ... if the WEEKDAY is "2"?

These might be useful for `ss`:

```
(car_id, inst_id, start_time)
(inst_id, car_id, finish_time)
```

`LIMIT  1` without `ORDER BY` leads to some random row being returned?  Is the `LIMIT` redundant?  Or is an `ORDER BY` needed?

Suggest you get some timings -- It is not obvious which of the `SELECTs` is chewing up the most CPU.

If the `PRIMARY KEY` of `cars` is `id`, then why test for `inst_id` and `active`?  Yikes!  You don't seem to have a PK for `cars`!  Please verify that every table has a PK.

Redundant:

```
              and  car_id = carid
              and  car_id = carid
```

Why twice?  And what tables are those columns in?  Please qualify columns so we can understand what is going on.

When `@stop_ser=0`, the procedure does nothing?  In which case, perform that test first, so you can avoid computing `@route`.

Change `start_time` to datatype `TIME`; then you can get rid of `DATE_FORMAT` in

```
      and  ss.start_time<=DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')
      AND  ss.finish_time>= date_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
```

Also, beware of the inequality tests, it may lead to some edge cases you did not want.

Don't use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` (eg, float(11,7)); it does rounding that is unnecessary.  Also, you can't get 7 decimal places for lat/lng except very near the equator and longitude=0.  More on precision:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices

After you have cleaned up those and provided the requested info, I will take another look.